turn on an LED with a pressure switch but it will not turn off until you reset the switch
So first off I'm new to all of this electronic stuff. I understand the basics but that is it...
so this is what I'm attempting to do.
I want a pressure switch that will turn on an LED light, but i need it to stay on no mater how many times the pressure switch is triggered. The only way to turn off the light would be with a reset button that would turn off the LED and reset the pressure switch back to normal.
For an example this could be used in a liquor cabinet. when the door is closed the LED is off and when the door is opened the light would be trigged and turn on the LED light. but no matter how many times that door is opened it will not turn off the LED. Only way to reset would be with the (secret) override button.
So the question is.. what parts would i need to build this. how do i connect them for this to work. i have the basics like the switch, led, and random parts. but i don't know how to wire it all together, I really don't know how the parts would work all together.
Thanks Dan

So what is the question? Sounds perfectly doable.

please edit the question into your post at top of this page ... then delete your comment... this site is not a forum where you add questions below your main post

@DanHladil We can't help you with the whole project, we can help you with specific parts, where are you stuck?

I'm stuck with this main question. What product will allow the light to stay on. is it a relay, solenoid, diode, chip i don't even know the right name I'm just lost.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This is a canonical circuit for an intro to silicon controlled rectifiers (SCRs). They are generally three terminal PNPN devices with an anode, cathode, and gate terminal. The device blocks current flow between the anode and cathode until a small current pulse is applied to the gate whereupon it latches into a conductive state and allows current to flow from the anode to the cathode until cathode current falls below some small holding value (Ih).
Use a normally open switch on the gate and a normally closed switch on the anode in series with your LED and resistor. The values of R1 and R2 are dependent on your LED's forward current and SCR's trigger current, respectively. There are plenty of devices out there in a TO92 package with Ih of <5mA so you should be able to find something that works.
If for some reason you are married to a normally-open reset switch, you can place it in parallel across the SCR to shunt current around it and turn it off.

Brilliant! Solves the problem in a much simpler way than using CMOS logic gates. Especially so if the lamp needs a different voltage than the CMOS parts and/or if the lamp needs more current than the CMOS can source or sink.

@DanHladil, Note: R1 is only there to limit the current through a bare LED chip (D1). If you're not using a bare LED—if you're using any kind of a lamp module that is designed to run from a constant voltage power supply, then you don't need R1. You do need to be aware of the current and voltage ratings for the SCR, you might need to be aware that the SCR will "drop" one to two volts from the supply voltage, and if the power of the lamp is more than a few tens of milliwatts, then you may need to mount the SCR on some kind of heat sink.

@DanHladil, also note: Maybe this is obvious, but any momentary power interruption will reset the state to "off." If your application requires the reset switch to be hidden/inaccessible, then you'll also need the power supply to be hidden/inaccessible.

Good answer, I haven't actually had a chance to play around with SCRs yet in my now 8 years of study and employment within electronics, useful circuit to know

Sounds like what you want is an SR Latch (that's your Google search term). The specifics of implementation will of course depend greatly on what switches you are planning to use - no exact part numbers are given in the question so I can't help there.
You may need additional circuitry such as a comparator for the pressure switch, a pull-up resistor for the reset switch, current limiting resistor for the LED, etc. but again, this is application-dependent and beyond the scope of this question.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The schematic gives a very high-level overview of roughly what you want, the S (SET) and R (RESET) inputs toggle the output (Q) high and low respectively. Consecutive triggers at the same input are 'ignored' (i.e. once the output is set high, any other pulses at the SET input will not change the output until the output is reset by a pulse at the RESET input).
Note that the inputs in the schematic are 'active low' (indicated by the bar over the S and R) which means the input should usually be high, and should only go low when the switch is activated. You can use a dedicated SR latch chip such as the 4044 IC (datasheet) or it can be constructed from NAND gates using the 4011 IC (datasheet). A quick Google for "NAND SR Latch" will return plenty of results (both articles and images) for how to create this circuit, as well as explaining how it works.
Alternatively, you could use a latching relay, a dual-coil latching relay will be far easier to drive using your intended two switch approach than a single-coil latching relay so look closely at what type you are buying if you choose to go this route. Driving a relay has its own considerations, but again, beyond the scope of this question.

thank you. This is a great start for me. thanks Again.
